# Enable radio button only for admin user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In the application I'm developing I have an admin panel in that panel there a function to create, edit and delete users.

In the form I create 3 user types using a while loop which drags data from a database and the 3 user types are:

- Admin
- Manager
- User

HTML Form:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: SiNUX
 * Date: 4/6/2017
 * Time: 3:41 PM
 */

session_start();
include_once("../iConnect/handShake.php");

$getUserRole = "SELECT * FROM userroles ORDER BY urId ASC";
$getUserRoleQuery = $dbConnect -> query($getUserRole);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Timer User Creation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/main.css">

    <!-- Java Scripts -->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/svrTimeDate.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/reload.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/setMsg.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/userCreatFunctions.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/multiScript.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/getIds.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="pauseLoad4()">
    <div id="divCenter" class="box">
        <label id="userName">Hello <?php echo $_SESSION["fName"]." ".$_SESSION["lName"]; ?></label><br><br>
        <label id="uId" hidden>1</label>
        <div style="width: 166px; position: absolute; left: 642px; top: 20px; height: 44px;">
            <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33">
        </div>
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <label id="date" style="margin-left: 50px;"></label><br><br>
        <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" style="margin-left: 10px;" onkeyup="checkEmpty();">
        <label for="lName" style="margin-left: 8px;">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" style="margin-left: 10px;" onkeyup="checkEmpty();" disabled>
        <label for="uName" style="margin-left: 8px;">User Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="uName" name="uName" style="margin-left: 7px;" onkeyup="checkEmpty();" disabled><br><br>
        <label for="pWord1" style="margin-left: 8px;" >Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pWord1" name="pWord1" style="margin-left: 17px;" onkeyup="checkLength();" disabled>
        <label for="pWord2" style="margin-left: 8px;">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pWord2" name="pWord2" style="margin-left: 8px;" onkeyup="checkPass();" disabled>
        <label for="uTeam" style="margin-left: 8px;">Team</label>
        <select name="uTeam" id="uTeam" style="width: 170px;" onchange="teamId(this.id);enableRoles();" disabled>
            <option></option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="uTeamId" id="uTeamId" hidden><br><br>
        <div id="userRoles">
            <label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><label for="uAttrib" style="margin-left: 250px;">User Attributes:</label><br>
            <?php while ($row = $getUserRoleQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="<?php echo $row["urId"]; ?>"
                <?php if ($_SESSION["uRole"] != "1" && $row["userRole"] == "Admin" ){?> disabled <?php } ?>><?php echo $row["userRole"]; }?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="tl" name="tl" value="yes" style="margin-left: 120px;" disabled>Team Leader
        </div>
        <label id="msgID" hidden></label>
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <div id="sbmBtns">
            <input type="button" value="Reset" name="reset" id="reset" class="btn" onclick="resetForm()">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn" onclick="pauseLoad3();" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I use a JavaScript to validate the form and to enable the next text box if the validation criteria is met.

JavaScript:

```
function checkEmpty() {
    var msg = document.getElementById('msg'),
        fName = document.getElementById('fName'),
        lName = document.getElementById('lName'),
        uName = document.getElementById('uName'),
        pass1 = document.getElementById("pWord1");

    //Using ajax made the function to check if the text box value is empty or not
    //when that text box has focus.
    if ($("#fName").is(':focus')){
        if (fName.value.length <= 3){
            msg.innerHTML = "First name is too short";
        }else{
            msg.innerHTML = "";
            lName.disabled = false;
        }
    }

    if ($("#lName").is(':focus')){
        if (lName.value === fName.value){
            msg.innerHTML = "Last and first name can't be the same";
            pass1.disabled = true;
        }else{
            if (lName.value.length <= 3){
                msg.innerHTML = "Last name is too short";
            }else{
                msg.innerHTML = "";
                uName.disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($("#uName").is(':focus')){
            if (uName.value.length <= 3){
                msg.innerHTML = "User name is too short";
                pass1.disabled = true;
            }else{
                if(uName.value.length > 0){
                    checkUname();
                }
            }
    }

    function checkUname() {

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                if (xmlhttp.responseText === "1"){
                    msg.innerHTML="Username taken";
                    pass1.disabled = true;
                }else{
                    msg.innerHTML = "";
                    pass1.disabled = false;
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","../Functions/matchUname.php?uName="+uName.value,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

function checkLength() {
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("pWord1"),
        pass2 = document.getElementById("pWord2"),
        passLength1 = pass1.value.length;

    if(passLength1 <= 4){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="Password is less than 4 characters!";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="";
        pass2.disabled = false;
    }
}

function checkPass() {
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("pWord1"),
        pass2 = document.getElementById("pWord2"),
        uTeam = document.getElementById("uTeam"),
        matchColor = "#66cc66",
        noMatchColor = "#ff6666";

    if (pass1.value === pass2.value){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="Passwords match!";
        pass1.style.backgroundColor = matchColor;
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = matchColor;
        uTeam.disabled = false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML ="Passwords do not match!";
        pass1.style.backgroundColor = noMatchColor;
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = noMatchColor;
    }
}

function enableRoles() {
    var team = document.getElementById("uTeam").value,
        teamId = document.getElementById("uTeamId").value,
        tlCheck = document.getElementById("tl"),
        role = document.getElementsByClassName("userRoles");

    if (team !== ""){
        //For loop to enable radio buttons
        for (var i = 1; i < role.length; i++){
            role[i].disabled = false;

                //This part will take the team is from uTeamId text box
                //send it to getTeam.php checks if that team has a leader if that team has a leader
                //"set" value will be returned making the check box for team attribute team leader disabled.
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

                }else{

                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

                    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

                        // document.getElementById("msgID").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        tlCheck.disabled = xmlhttp.responseText === "set";

                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("POST","../Functions/getTeam.php?teamId="+teamId,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

        }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    /*Register the change element to #roles
     || When clicked...*/

    //This code base was originally developed by zer00ne I'm using it under his permission
    //Thanks man

    var form = document.getElementById('userRoles');

    if (form){
        form.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

                /* Determine if the e.target (radio that's clicked)
                 || is NOT e.currentTarget (#roles)
                 */
                if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

                    // Assign variable to e.target
                    var target = e.target;

                    // Reference the submit button
                    var btn = document.querySelector('[name=submit]');

                    // Enable submit button
                    btn.disabled = false;

                    // call rolrDist() passing the target,value
                    roleDist(target.value);
                }
        }, false);
    }

    function roleDist(rank) {
        var display = document.getElementById("msg");

        if (rank !== null) {
            display.innerHTML = "All done! You can save";
        } else {
            display.innerHTML = "Please Select User Type";
        }
    }
});
```

It's working with out any errors but I want to disable the Admin user type if the logged in user is not a admin. I can get this done by using pure PHP but it breaks the flow of the form.

In my HTML/PHP form I have used PHP to archive what I'm describing but it not really what want to do I want use JavaScript or jQuery or AJAX to archive this.

The PHP I use:

```
 <div id="userRoles">
            <label for="userRoles">User Role:</label><label for="uAttrib" style="margin-left: 250px;">User Attributes:</label><br>
            <?php while ($row = $getUserRoleQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <input type="radio" class="userRoles" name="userRoles" value="<?php echo $row["urId"]; ?>"
                <?php if ($_SESSION["uRole"] != "1" && $row["userRole"] == "Admin" ){?> disabled <?php } ?>><?php echo $row["userRole"]; }?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="tl" name="tl" value="yes" style="margin-left: 120px;" disabled>Team Leader
        </div>
```

Can some direct me down the right path or show me how to do this.

**UPDATE:**
After talking with professionals I learned that what I was trying to do is to shoot my self in the foot by my own gun. It's a bad idea to use client side languages to handle security options and WE CAN'T TRUST THE USER. My main issues was the flow of the form but security trumps the beauty so this will be split in to another one which the normal user want even see the admin option.

I would like to leave this question here and don't mind if it get closed so others can learn something from my mistake.

Comment: If connected user is not an admin, user should not even see the admin options. This HAS TO BE managed server-side.

Comment: Whenever you have validation in the front end, you need to have the same validation in the back end. _Never_ trust data from the front end. Anyone can manipulate that data before it reaches your back end.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So I need to use my backed process PHP to re-validate the data am I right ?.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I just ditch java script make PHP make the admin option hidden if the user is not admin ?

Comment: Jack... Can you re-phrase that ?

Comment: No I was not being hostile or anything what I want know is with out using JavaScript to manipulate the radio button I use PHP and completely remove or hide the Admin option from the user.

Comment: Yes, you need to re-validate anything you validate in JS, if it is important. JS is executed in users browsers, where they have full access to change what ever they want. Having JS-validation is more for convenience, since you can show errors without even submitting the data, but you always need to do it in the back end as well.

Comment: Ok Jack... So you know you to determine if the connected user is an admin or not in order to show/hide admin options... So what is your question then?

Comment: Use a Content management system or create two separate PHP HTML file, one for the admin and other for regular users. Never trust users!!! One more thing use Preapr and Execut to get data from your database, more safe

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette my question was how to do the thing I've done using PHP in JavaScript or JQuery but it seems it will be shooting my self in the foot with my own gun. I do use a selector PHP which check the user and redirect them to the appropriate main UI  with menus made for that user type,

Comment: @JoseMarques can't use a CMS I have build this custom time management system for my current company.

Comment: «I've done using PHP in JavaScript or JQuery »... Hey Do you know WHEN those scripts execute and on which side? I think this is what you don't get.

Comment: So use the second part and, separate the user from the admin when you do the Login. If you want I can give you some tips like doing what you want, but it's never safe.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette PHP Server side other stuff client that I know and I do know when they execute and JavaScript based stuff can be manipulated by the user if he / she knows what they are doing. And I quote my self _it seems it will be shooting my self in the foot with my own gun_ I will be splitting the files.

Comment: @JoseMarques I'm doing that already using a PHP script which spits user's , Managers and Admins I just have create another file for Managers those are the only tier down from Admin.

Comment: @JoseMarques Why would prepared statements be more safe in a query without any parameters at all?

Comment: Jack.... lol... Put the gun down. Server-side stuff is mostly the PHP. It produces the HTML and fetch all is needed on the client side for the browser. All that is on client side is visible and manipulable by a wize guy. So your user-level security SHALL NOT be on client side...

Comment: In one word injection !!!  

SQL injection is a code injection technique that might destroy your database.

SQL injection is one of the most common web hacking techniques.

SQL injection is the placement of malicious code in SQL statements, via web page input.

Comment: Scripts which execute on client-side are JavaScript and jQuery... Even if it is written within a PHP file. They are juste "served".

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yep those Java stuff always run on the client computer.

Comment: @JoseMarques SQL injections is when SQL is insert in the parameters. If there isn't any parameters (dynamic parameters) in the query but just a hard coded query, there is ZERO risk for SQL injections.

Comment: @JoseMarques Appreciate if you can give me some helpful tips always want learn

Comment: Let us continue in chat ?!? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143346/taliking-script-sides

Comment: As for the injection you can do a google search, for more information. As for your code when doing a search for a permission you have to use parameters, such as ID, name and email, to access the specific information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to nail this one down...

After a nice [chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143346/taliking-script-sides), it appears that Jack (OP) has understood the importance not to manage user level security on client side.

The questions no longer needs more answer.
;)